# How to conditionally compile a templated function over the return type

Tags: c++, templates

If I template a function in C++ on the return type:

```
template<class T> T foo(int x) { };
```

I can use explicit template specialization to create a `double` instance:

```
template<> double foo<double>(int x) { };
```

I tried to use forward declaration to create an instance of an undefined `struct`:

```
struct bar;
template<> bar foo<bar>(int x) { }
```

This fails with `error: return type ‘struct bar’ is incomplete`. I *thought* this would be allowed, even after reading the accepted answer on [When to use forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/249341) since, until I create an instance of `foo<bar>`, the explicit templated code is never created. Clearly this is not the case (why not?).

Is it possible to have code for functions whose type might not exist at compile time, and only compile the code if the particular explicit specialization is instanced? The motivation for this is an "overloaded" struct reader, where the overload operations are procedurally generated before the compile (via a script).

Comment: Can you have the script also generate your specialization?

Comment: I think the compile error is because your function is returning a bar (not just a pointer or reference to a bar) which the compiler knows nothing about.  You may need to do some sort of preprocessor stuff here I'm not really sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *define* an specialization of a function you are defining the *function*, not a *function template*. The rules at this point are exactly the same as for any regular function and because you are using the type in a way that needs a complete type, the lack of a definition for `bar` makes your program ill-formed.

(The lack of a return statement also makes the program ill-formed...)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, if you don't provide the body of the `foo` function:

```
// some header file, probably
struct bar;
template<> bar foo<bar>(int x);

// somewhere else:

struct bar { 
    //blabla 
};

// the actual implementation
template<> bar foo<bar>(int x) {
    // do something
}
```

The forward declaration works only if you don't actually require the definition of `bar`. In your `foo` function's body, you need to know the size of that struct, that's why your code didn't work.